# Regex for one element or semi-colon separated list of max. 2 elements

Tags: regex

I need to match one or two time-ranges (in 24h-format) in a regex. The following two would be valid entries:

`12:30-15:00`

`12:30-15:00;17:20-20:00`

If there is an error anywhere (ie in the second time-range), then no match should be found.
ie
`12:30-15:00;17:20` is not a valid entry.

The regex for one time range I have written as follows (which could be improved to use only valid times, but that's the next step):

`(\d\d:\d\d\-\d\d:\d\d)`

Any hints on how to expand this to fit my aforementioned criteria?

Comment: `^(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](?:-(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])(?:;(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](?:-(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]))*$`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/96TY9z/1).

Comment: In PCRE, `^((?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](?:-(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]))(?:;(?1))*$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/96TY9z/2).

Comment: That is very impressive, Wiktor. Works perfectly. You can post this as an answer, I'll accept it gladly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
^(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]-(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](?:;(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]-(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])*$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/96TY9z/5). A shorter PCRE/Onigmo (Ruby) version:

```php
^((?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]-(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])(?:;(\g<1>))*$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/96TY9z/4).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string (in Ruby, `\A`)
- `((?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]-(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])` - Group 1:

  - `(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]` - first time string: an optional `0` or `1` and then any digit, or `2` and then `0`, `1`, `2` or `3` and then a `:` char and then a number from `00` to `59`
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]` - second time string
- `(?:;(\g<1>))*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `;` - a semi-colon
  - `(\g<1>)` - Repeat Group 1 pattern
- `$` - end of string.